# Git BASH location of script that is run from command line

Tags: bash, git-bash

__git_ps1 is a command I can run in the BASH shell and it runs no matter which directory it runs from.  How can I tell where this batch file is sourced from?  I checked all my $PATH folders and it isn't in any of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command is actually a stand-alone script in your path, you can use the type command to locate it:

`type __git_ps1`

However, it could be a function or an alias, in which case, the output of the type command won't be terribly helpful. (Apart from at least letting you know that it's a function or an alias.)

[Edit]

Just realized this is from git completion, it's (probably?) defined in /etc/bash_completion.d/git.

Comment: It is a function, and type does not tell it where it is.

Comment: @Amir: Right, sorry -- poor wording. I meant, if it is actually a script, it will tell you where it is, but it may be a func or an alias, in which case, it won't. I'll clarify.

Comment: You can scan the output of `bash --login -x` or `bash -x` to look for configuration files that are sourced when `bash` starts. One of those (possibly `/etc/bash_completion.d/git`, as Alex points out) should have a definition for `__git_ps1`.